Confusing Components in a Sentence: adverbial modifier OR object in a prepositional phrase
I'm trying to understand the grammatical role of a phrase in a sentence. The sentence in question is:
"And all without the government having to spend any money up-front, which is amazing."
In this sentence, what grammatical function does "having to spend any money up-front" serve? It may work as a gerund phrase or the object in a prepositional phrase, but I'm unsure about its specific role. Is it acting as an adverbial modifier, or does it serve another purpose?

Its function is that of predicate in the gerund-participial clause "the government having to spend any money up-front".


And all without the government having to spend any money up-front, which is amazing.

I add to what @BillJ said.
The gerund-participle phrase is the predicate of the nonfinite clause:

the government having to spend any money up-front

The nonfinite clause is the object of preposition without.
A similar example is found in sense 4 definition of without

​4 not doing the action mentioned


without somebody doing something The party was organized without her knowing anything about it.


Very clear. Thanks a lot for your help!
